# passing a string as an argument when the dummy has specified length

Tags: string, fortran, fortran90

if I have this code

```
module test
contains
   subroutine xx(name)
      character(len=20), intent(in), optional :: name

      if (present(name)) then
         print *, name
      else
         print *, "foo"
      endif
   end subroutine
end module
program x
   use test

   call xx()
   call xx("foo2")
end program
```

It will not compile since "foo2" is not of length 20, and the compiler complains

```
test.f90(17): error #7938: Character length argument mismatch.   ['foo2']
   call xx("foo2")
-----------^
```

How can I make this thing work, without modifying the subroutine dummy len specification ? Is it mandatory to have an intermediate variable declared with the same length and pass that at call time ?

Answer (score 8):

Standard language can be hard to understand.   I read the clause cited by @kemiisto as requiring length `(dummy arg) <= length` (actual arg).  Here length `(dummy arg) = 20` and `length (actual arg) = 4`, so length `(dummy arg) > length (actual arg)`, which is not allowed by the clause.   The clause talks about truncating the actual to match the dummy, if needed, not padding it with blanks.

The code will work if you replace `character(len = 20)` with `character(len = *)`   Is there a problem with this since you didn't want to modify the length of the dummy argument specification?

Comment: the problem is that the routine with character(len=20) is in a part of the code I am not supposed to modify.

Comment: Then I suggest writing a "glue" function that transforms its arguments to character (len=20) and applying this function to any argument of xx that might not be long enough: call xx (makelen20 ("foo2"))

Answer (score 3):

The reason this error occurs is your method is allowed to read/write up to `len=20` characters to the dummy argument `name`. Your string literal is less than this amount and your compiler is alerting you to this fact. Even though it is declared `intent(in)` you could read beyond the actual argument length and cause an access violation, etc.

You should probably stick to `len=*` with dummy arguments and use `len` or `len_trim` when determining how many characters it is safe to read/write.

Or if you must keep the `len=20`, you should use a temporary variable used to pass values into that method. Or something uglier like `"hello"//repeat(" ", 15)`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me like standard compliant behavior.

Fortran 2003, 12.4.1.2 Actual arguments associated with dummy data objects

> If a scalar dummy argument is of type
>   default character, the length len of
>   the dummy argument shall be less than
>   or equal to the length of the actual
>   argument. The dummy argument becomes
>   associated with the leftmost len
>   characters of the actual argument.

However gfortran just rise a warning message

> Warning: Character length of actual argument shorter than of dummy argument 'name' (4/20) at (1)

It seems that Intel Fortran compiler is more standard compliant in that respect. So intermediate variable is probably the only option.

Or actually just declaring a variable is option because you do not have one in your code. You have literal constant. Hard-coded values are not a good idea anyway. =)