# Derived-type custom constructor not being called in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to make a custom data-type constructor by overloading the type name. However, when making the call, the default constructor gets called instead. I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

Here's a code snippet that has the problem.

```
    module test

    type, public :: foo
        character(512)   ::  str
        logical          ::  flag1
        logical          ::  flag2
    end type

    ! overload foo data-type
    interface foo
        module procedure make_foo
    end interface

    contains

    ! custom constructor
    function make_foo(str, flag1) result(self)
        implicit none
        type(foo)  ::  self
        character(512), intent(in)      :: str
        logical, intent(in), optional   :: flag1

        self % str  = str       ! this needs to be passed

        self % flag1 = .false.  ! this needs to be optional, and is false by default
        if (present(flag1)) self % flag1 = flag1

        self % flag2 = .false.  ! this cannot be passed and is always false by default

    end function

end module

program tmp
    use test
    implicit none 
    type(foo) :: a

    a = foo("hello") ! error here
end program
```

I want to have a custom constructor that requires `str` to be passed, that allows for the optional specification of `flag1` and that deals with `flag2` always by itself.
When testing the data-type using its constructor, it uses the default constructor and it complains for missing components.

```
No initializer for component 'flag1' given in the structure constructor at (1)
```

I am using gfortran 10.2.0

Comment: Why is your dummy argument `str` a `character(512)`? `make_foo` cannot be called with actual argument `"hello"` in this case.

Comment: @francescalus it's the mandatory argument that needs to be passed to `self%name` , that is also a `character(512)`. I'm trying to pass `"hello"` to `str` in `make_foo`, and than store it in `foo%name`.

Comment: If you want `str` to be `character(512)` then you need the actual argument to have at least length 512. `"Hello"` isn't that long. I see no reason why `str` shouldn't be `character(*)`.

Comment: @francescalus You are right, it actually works if I just use a `character(*)` on the constructor function. Thanks! I was under the impression it would have added spaces after `"Hello"` automatically to get to 512 chars, like what it does if you declare `character(512) :: b = "hello"`.

Comment: Actual arguments are not automatically "cast" (padded/converted) to match requirements of the dummy. For characters in particular, you can see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4780069/3157076).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment statement

```
a = foo("hello")
```

is taken to be a reference to the generic `foo` if possible, and a reference to the default structure constructor for the type `foo` otherwise.

In the case here, the generic `foo` has one specific interface: `make_foo`. For reference to the generic `foo` we need `foo("hello")` to be consistent with `make_foo`.

The dummy argument `str` is declared as `character(512)` and so we are not allowed to reference it with actual argument the literal constant `"Hello"`: that constant is (much) [too short](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4780069/3157076).<sup>1</sup>

The compiler falls back to the default structure constructor, and then (rightly) complains that there are components without default initialization which haven't been given values.

This reference can be fixed in one of two ways:

- provide an actual argument of length at least 512
- make `str` shorter, or better, assumed length

To address a concern about assumed length `str`: even if it's length 5, it still can be used in the assignment `self%str = str` as it will be padded with blanks at the end to make its length up to the 512 of `self%str`.

---

Whether that's strictly sufficient to deem the reference "inconsistent" is irrelevant: in trying to do this one doesn't have a Fortran program, so one can't demand the compiler tries that reference.